# Python Mock Change Return Value based on Call Count

Tags: python, pytest

I have to test the behaviour of a parser which gets data from a remote API.
The data are paginated, which means I receive a JSON with meta info about current page and last page.
So, I would like to test the parser with different pages of data.

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

def load():
    file_name = f"plants_info_{load.counter}.json"
    print(file_name)
    with open(f"./{file_name}", "r") as file:       
       data = json.load(file)
       load.counter += 1
       return (data['data'], data['meta'])

load.counter = 1


class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    backend = Backend()

    @patch.object(backend, "get_info", side_effect=load())
    def test_get_info(self, nothing):
        """Testing get_stations"""
             data = self.backend.get_stations(community_id=1)
             # doing asserts...
```

The backend.get_stations_info is a function like:
def get_stations_info(community_id=0):
page = 1
plants, meta = self.get_info(
url=url,
field='data')

```
   while meta["current_page"] < meta["last_page"]:
        page += 1
        _, meta = self.get_info(params={"page": page})
        ....
```

While, the patched/mocked function get_info shall return a simple JSON structure.

I have 2 problems:

1- the load function returns the last value, i.e. the content of file plants_info_2.json. While, I would get differente files on different calls:

2-If I remove the "nothing" variable from `def test_get_info(self, nothing)` I get
 `TypeError: TestCase.test_get_stations_info() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Answer (score 0):

As simple as to change the call:

`@patch.object(backend, "get_info", side_effect=load())`

to

`@patch.object(backend, "get_info", side_effect=load)`